# i can't declare a cursor in MySQL, always error 1064

Tags: mysql, cursor

DELCARE EMP_CUR CURSOR
FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL;

it always pops up an error message saying  'unexpected delcare_sym' and it's No.1064, something with syntax, but i don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: give your try code here..

Comment: Show the SQL around that line, especially everything preceding it. You may have a problem with how/where you're using that line.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, I also and only typed 'USE LEARNSQL;' before that line, because the EMPLOYEE_TBL is in LEARNSQL database, but that's it, nothing else, and I'm sure thee table is well-created.

Comment: sorry, i don't really know...@VishalZanzrukia